# How to change the color of a value depending on certain conditions using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am working on spring MVC project, in which I am passing the data from controller to jsp page. And then I am showing the data in my jsp page.

Below is my table row in JSP page in which I am showing the data and that object I am getting from the controller -

```
<tr>
    <th>${m.machineName}</th>
    <td>${m.Fresh_95}</td>
    <td>${m.Fresh_99}</td>  
</tr>
```

Now what I need to do is if the value of `m.Fresh_95` is greater than `100.00` then only I would like to show this value `{m.Fresh_95}` in red color otherwise I won't change the color. Is this possible to do in jquery and jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give it a class for easy look up and use jquery to add a class if necessary...

```
<td class="color-changer">${m.Fresh_95}</td>
```

javascript:
grab the text value and convert it to a number with a basic stripping regex since I don't know what the value of this will be (dollar amount, any text with digits, etc):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.color-changer').each(function(){
        if(Number($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")) > 100)
            $(this).addClass('red');
    });
});
```

and of course give your .red class some css:

```
.red{
    color:#ff0000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kai. Works fine..Appreciated your help. Is there any way I can make it little bit bold red color if possible?

Comment: updated. just add font-weight:bold to the css .red class

Comment: Cool.. Make sense..and it worked as well. Actually I am not a UI/Jquery guy so still learning some stuff. I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340231/how-to-reload-a-div-without-reloading-the-jsp-page-using-jquery). See if you can help me out. Any help will be appreciated.